# differential equation $xf'(x)-f(x){\rm log}(f(x))=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could anyone solve following differential equation?

$xf'(x)-f(x){\rm log}(f(x))=0$

where $x$ is real value and $f(x)$ is real-valued function.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? This equation is separable, so at least give that a try. One substitution worth trying is $f(x) = \exp(u(x))$ for the resulting integral.

Comment: Or you could just look through a list of your favorite functions and try each one of them...which is how I solved it in my head just now.

Comment: What did you try? Try like:when  $\log (f(x)) =u $ then $ u'/u= dx/x $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$x\left(\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)-\log(f(x))=0$$ and let $v=\log(f(x).$

Comment: I think that my solution has some non-necessary algebraic manipulation. This way is better.

Comment: That's very helpful hint. I successfully solve the equation and solution was correspond to Alexandre Frias' answer!

Answer (score 1):

My attempt is

$$ x f'(x) = f(x) \log(f(x)) \implies x\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\log(f(x))$$

Adding $\log(f(x))$ in both sides of the equality

$$x\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\log(f(x))=2\log(f(x))\implies \frac{d}{dx}(x \log(f(x))=2\log(f(x))$$

Multiplying both sides by $x$

$$x\frac{d}{dx}(x \log(f(x))=2(x\log(f(x)))$$

substituting $y(x)=x\log(f(x))$

$$x\frac{d}{dx}y(x)=2 y(x)\implies y(x)=cx^2$$

thus $x \log(f(x))=c x^2\implies f(x)=e^{cx}$

Comment: Thank you for exact solution. The result was the same with Bumblebee's one anyway!